Way to put __func__ into particular linker section?
I'm working on an embedded system with limited flash space.  I want to generate logging statements including the function name and so make use of __func__ (or __FUNCTION__ I'm not too fussy in this regard so long as it works on gcc).  I'd like to control where those string literals go in memory.
Consider something like this:
extern void Log(char const *function, char const *fmt, ...);

Log(__func__, "error %d", 4);

I can move fmt into a particular section with some __attribute__ hackery ...
#include <stdio.h>

#define Log(function, fmt, ...)                                              \
  ({                                                                         \
      static const char fmt_[] __attribute__((section(".mystr"))) = (fmt);   \
      printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);                                            \
   }                                                                         \
  )

int
main(void)
{
        Log(__func__, "error %d\n", 4);
}

(for example, I won't really be using printf but it expresses the intent).
But I've failed to find a way to do similar with __func__.  It isn't a string literal (it's a const char[]) so can't be used to initialise a char[] to locate in a different section.
I considered using a macro to turn generate an array initialiser:
#define STR64INIT(s) \
 { \
        sizeof (s) > 0 ? s[0] : 0, \
        sizeof (s) > 1 ? s[1] : 0, \
        // ...
 }

static char const function_name[64] __attribute__((section ("mystr"))) = STR64INIT(__func__);

But my initialiser isn't constant so that won't fly.
Any suggestions?
Note that I don't want to move all strings to a different section, just some strings -- those used for debug logging.  And I am aware that moving strings around won't automatically save space -- and might indeed increase it -- but trust me I am playing the long game.

Even if this would have worked, you wouldn't be saving any memory but the contrary. You'd be allocating the local static const char[] in some place and __func__ would still be allocated too, wherever the linker thinks that strings ought to be (.rodata or some such). Is it more important to have the strings in one place or to save flash?

Why would you want to allocate static const char[] for every block? Sounds like every block will have separate __func__, loosing you memory, preventing optimization. Any suggestions? Add mystr section to .rodata and let linker pack it.

I can move fmt into a particular section with some __attribute__ hackery ...  That is not only pointless but also actually detrimental, as @Lundin pointed out.  It will cause problems if the format string passed isn't a proper initializer for a static char [].  And nevermind that using printf() to log to stdout is problematic, too.  Among other issues, the process is irrevocably tied to whatever stdout is attached to.  And whatever stdout is attached to is locked in place as long as the process is running.

I realize this doesn't help you ... but a little bit of history: Old versions of gcc let you use __FUNCTION__ instead of __func__ here. The former was treated as string literal while the latter always was a variable. That means you used to be able to say static const char fmt_[] __attribute__((section(".mystr"))) = __FUNCTION__ ## (fmt); (concatenate it with other string literals). This changed - current versions of gcc treat the two alike. Compare https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/gcc/Function-Names.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html ...

Thanks @FrankH.  There is some interesting discussion about the history of this in https://groups.google.com/g/comp.std.c/c/AvdeRxPTT2o.
